# Url rewrite - Simple issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue with URL rewrite.

I'm simply trying to redirect smart url like **www.name.com/demo/profile** to the existing url: **www.name.come/demo/index.php?s=profile**

I put my .htaccess in the root directory.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/([a-z]+) demo/index.php?s=$1& [NC,L]
```

If I write something like **www.name.com/demo/profile** it doesn't work.

Mod Rewrite on the server is active and it work (I have tried other examples).

Thanks!

> **Update**

With **numbers** it works.

My rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/([0-9]+) demo/index.php?s=$1& [NC,L]
```

**Smart url:** www.name.com/demo/1
**Existing url:** www.name.come/demo/index.php?s=1

Why it doesn't work with characters?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? - it *should* for the specific example given.

Comment: What error do you see when you go to the url?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /demo/profile was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either add some conditions for your rule or make the matching a bit more restrictive. Try either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^demo/([a-z]+) demo/index.php?s=$1& [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/([a-z]+)$ demo/index.php?s=$1& [NC,L]
```

So that your regex doesn't end up matching "index.php".

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work.
Always the same error:
Not Found
The requested URL /demo/profile was not found on this server.